# Office 365 JavaScript API, redirect back to WP app after launching Store

Tags: api, windows-phone, office365

I am creating a Windows Phone app using HTML And JavaScript. I am able to add connected services and have selected "Users and Groups" and given it Read permissions.

I am then making the following calls on button click:

```
var authContext = new O365Auth.Context();
authContext.getIdToken("https://TestDomain.onmicrosoft.com/TestWebApi").then(
    function (token){
    }
);
```

`Services/Office365/Settings.js` has been edited to the following:

```
    Settings.clientId = "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";

    Settings.authUri = "https://login.windows.net/common/";

    Settings.redirectUri = "ms-app://s-1-15-2-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx/";
```

I got the `redirectUri` value by calling the following function:

```
Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationBroker.getCurrentApplicationCallbackUri();
```

I do get the login screen for my organization and I am able to provide credentials and it tries to redirect it back to my application, but then I get asked the following question:

> "You need to install an app for this task. Would you like to search for one in the Store?"

If I click on yes, it takes me to the store and says "No apps found". If I click on no, it doesn't do anything.

How could I possibly get it redirected back to my app?

Answer (score 0):

The connected services experience only works in Multi-device hybrid apps (a.k.a. Cordova), not in Windows Phone apps.

Comment: Thanks Louri!! In that case, If I have to authenticate a user on windows phone via AAD, then what are the options? ADAL is also not supported on windows phone and seems like connected services is only supported for hybrid apps.

Comment: Connected services experience is currently enabled for Store apps, including Windows Phone non-Silverlight apps, and they have ADAL support. ADAL for Silverlight for WindowsPhone 8.1 was also released recently. Android and iOS are also supported by ADAL. For earlier Windows Phone versions, you can find a reference implementation of the O/Auth flow on Vittorio Bertocci's blog www.cloudidentity.com. Also, ADAL is open-source.